# How to disable kernel upgrade on Ubuntu Server 21 64 Bit on Raspberry Pi 4b?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, kernel, update

How can I disable kernel upgrades on a fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 21 64-bit OS for arm64 architectures on a Raspberry Pi 4b with 4gb?

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678630/how-can-i-avoid-kernel-updates) source, I tried:

```
sudo apt-mark hold 5.11.0-1007-raspi
```

because the output of `uname -r` is `5.11.0-1007-raspi` which is the kernel I want to preserve. After running the `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` command, the output of `uname -r` is still:

```
5.11.0-1007-raspi
```

and not:

```
5.11.0-1007-raspi
5.11.0-1008-raspi
```

as it is without the hold command. However, the `sudo apt upgrade` command still presents a pink/purple screen prompting for the kernel upgrade to `5.11.0-1008-raspi`. This indicates I did not disable the kernel upgrade correctly. Hence I would like to ask: *how can I disable kernel upgrading in Ubuntu Server 21 64-bit OS for arm64 architectures on a Raspberry Pi 4b with 4gb?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as indicated in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885120/avoid-updating-kernel-as-i-need-a-specific-kernel-for-my-processor?noredirect=1&lq=1) link one can inspect which kernels are installed using:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

which can return something like:

```
.. linux-image-5.11.0-1007-raspi ..
.. linux-image-raspi ..
```

which I believe are kernel versions.

Next one can set these kernel versions to `hold` using the interpretation of the commands from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885120/avoid-updating-kernel-as-i-need-a-specific-kernel-for-my-processor?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
sudo -s
echo linux-image-5.11.0-1007-raspi hold | dpkg --set-selections
echo linux-image-raspi hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

one can verify they are set correctly set to `hold` using:

```
echo linux-image-5.11.0-1007-raspi hold | dpkg --set-selections
echo linux-image-raspi hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

The output of both of those commands should start with `hi` where the `h` means `held` according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63293/blocking-kernel-updates-with-dpkg) link.

Next, one can run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and verify the kernel versions have stayed unchanged with:

```
uname -r
```

Which should output:

```
5.11.0-1007-raspi
```

and

```
ls -1 /lib/modules
```

Which also should output:

```
5.11.0-1007-raspi
```